# How to add an xml tag using actionscript 3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

My XML is

```
<imglist>
  <url>data</url>
  <title>title</title>
</imglist>
```

Here, I want insert `<image></image>` this tag. which means I need the output like

```
  <imglist>
    <image>
     <url>data</url>
     <title>title</title>
    </image>
  </imglist>
```

Any answers????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do recommend [this URL,](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e68.html) with official API and explanation about how to assembling and transforming XML objects.

You have the prependChild() method or the appendChild() method to add a property to the beginning or end of an XML object’s list of properties. Also the insertChildBefore() method or the insertChildAfter() method to add a property before or after a specified property.

You can also use curly brace operators ( **{ and }** ) to pass data by reference (from other variables) when constructing XML objects.

A quick solution (not telling you that is the best) for your answer:

```
  var xml:XML = <imglist><url>data</url><title>title</title></imglist>;

  var newXML:XML = <imglist><image>{xml.url}{xml.title}</image></imglist>
  trace(newXML);
```

Comment: Thank you.... But based on some conditions I have to add more then one image tag inside the image tag......I think there is no optimized code for this.....

Comment: using these methods prependChild, appendChild, insertChildBefore and insertChildAfter you can achieve what do you want.

Answer (score 0):

Nodes can be created dynamically simply by referencing them. If you reference a node that doesn't exist it will be created for you like:

```
var xml:XML = <imglist><url>data</url><title>title</title></imglist>;
xml.image = "myimage";
//node image now exist
//you can also remove nodes this way:
delete xml.image;
```